# send email automatically monthly using asp .net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, email

I am developing a tuition fee management system using asp .net MVC for a university assignment. I am quite new with asp .net just learn it this April 2021. One of the requirements is that the system automatically sends an email every month to every user as a reminder about the outstanding balance. So how do I start to develop this requirement since I've been searching and only found tutorials email send manually and to one user only?

Answer (score 0):

There is not built-in functionality in .NET that runs your code once a month, but there are several tools to do this. If you are using Azure, AWS or GCP (or any other cloud platform), you’d might consider a serverless Function to do this. These Functions can be triggered once a month by the cloud provider.

If you’re not hosting it in the cloud (or want to avoid any provider-specific features), you can use for instance Quartz (https://www.quartz-scheduler.net) or Hangfire (https://www.hangfire.io). There are many libraries available, all with their pros and cons. Hangfire for instance has a dashboard built-in to monitor and debug any issues, but this also costs some server resources and might be an overkill if you have a single job to run.

You should however take into account that communication with an SMTP server is quite time-consuming. Sending thousands of emails could therefore take a lot of time. Especially if you are using serverless Functions, this will become an issue due to the time-limits that apply for these Functions. Also when you run these as jobs in Quartz or Hangfire, you want to take into account this job might be aborted halfway. Therefore, you usually insert those mails into a queue (or database) and then have a second process to actually send these mails. Maybe even via a specialized email delivery service?